# How to get reports from my badmail folder?

Tags: .net, email, windows-server-2003, report

Using Win Server 2003 we send once every while we send out 200k+ emails and obviously the badmail folder get filled up. Its easy to delete them but I started looking for some way to actually get some statistics back from the bad mail but I cannot find any tools?

How can I find out how many Non Deliveries/ Delayed there are and possibly a list for each. Or am I looking at this from the bottoms end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only reason to monitor the badmail folder is because your
>   incomming mailbox does not accept emails or does not exist. So SMTP
>   IIS/Exchange will put them in the bad mail folder. If you have a
>   mailbox then it will put these files in the mailbox folder with
>   exactly the same files, but also will accept incomming bounce
>   backs/replies from other servers.

Write my own service to monitor a file using the .NET [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Class

1 Problem i encountered was that `FileSystemWatcher` reports filecreations onCreate-- but the Parent program can still be writting the file if you try to query it so it will thrown an exception.fileNotAccessible. (The only way to determine if a file is in use is trying to open it and catch the exception)

To overcome that problem i just catch that exception and put the file name into a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and in a Timer of 1-5minutes i re query the `Queue` filenames- by then the file should have been written and closed by the parent program.

I then parse the email content based on error code, reason, etc (bounced mails)  and insert it into my DB - I get allot of out of office mails too.
I did not use any email parser DLL's but for robust email parsing i would suggest you find something as it seems emails follow a standard.. but not very strict and they tend to vary slighlty.
[Email Parser example](http://www.mime4.net/)

I do all the magic required to make my class a service, install it on your mail server and let it monitor it.